# fflush(stdout) in eclipse build error: can't open output file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I put fflush(stdout) in between printf and scanf as suggested in the Internet. However, I got the following build error:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 
-o "src\\linkedlist.o" "..\\src\\linkedlist.cpp" 
g++ -o linkedlist.exe "src\\linkedlist.o" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-   
mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file linkedlist.exe: Permission   
denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The IDE I am using is eclipse. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Most likely your `linkedlist.exe` is still running. Check in taskmanager.

Comment: Make sure you didn't leave the debugger running. Also look upon sites that suggest you use `printf` and `scanf` in c++ with a certain amount of skepticism. Odds are too good they're teaching you C and not C++.

Comment: I re-built the project successfully in the console, and everything is OK without changing anything. However, this fflush(stdout) didn't fix my original problem: I still don't have any printouts in the console. I couldn't input anything via this scanf statement , either.

Comment: I myself believe the best way to do input and output in C++ eclipse is to use cin (instead of scanf) and cout.